# Linux (Ubuntu): How to get the path to a mounted Windows folder?

Tags: ubuntu, network-shares

I have mounted a Windows share using the GUI in Ubuntu. Now I would like to access it using the Terminal application. However, I don't know its path. I thought it should be in /mnt, but it isn't there.

**Edit**
The mount command currently gives the following output:

```
francis@francis-desktop:~$ mount
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/francis/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=francis)
/dev/sda2 on /media/34DCF260DCF21C34 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
francis@francis-desktop:~$
```

Comment: what's the mount command output?

Comment: @Sunny see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

It is the GVFS line.

Try the commands:

```
smbstatus

gvfs-mount -l
```

To see your gvfs mounts, if you have package gvfs-bin installed.